# r regex extract text before number including it

Tags: r, regex, string

there, I'm trying to extract the text before the number, including it, using regex in R.

As an example:

`string <- "Fallen tree at Barth Avenue nº 34. Center Cause Effect (CCE) #omg"`

Desired result: `"Fallen tree at Barth Avenue nº 34"`

I have found some ways to do this task without including the number, but that is not what I need.
`sub(pattern='[0-9]+.*', replacement='', x=string)
"Fallen tree at Barth Avenue nº "`

thks in advance

Comment: Like this `.*?\d+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can capture the characters that start (`^`) with zero or more non-digits followed by one or more numbers as a group followed by other characters and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the capture group

```
sub("^([^0-9]*\\d+).*", "\\1", string)
#[1] "Fallen tree at Barth Avenue nº 34"
```

Comment: `\D` uses less steps than `[^0-9]` (according to regex101.com) and assuming it's valid in R

Comment: @ctwheels  Yes, it is valid, It needs to be escaped